java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find servlet [] in the servlet context
I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application to AWS lambda. After deploying i am facing issue accessing the endpoint. I am getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find servlet [] in the servlet context . I have attached the Screenshot of cloudwatch with Docker and Lambda class file. Please help!!

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:17
# Copy function code and runtime dependencies from Maven layout
COPY target/classes ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY target/dependency/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "com.platform.Layout.StreamLambdaHandler::handleRequest" ]


package com.platform.plantlayout;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequest;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyResponse;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class StreamLambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StreamLambdaHandler.class);
    private static final SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;
    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Layout.class);
            // If you are using HTTP APIs with the version 2.0 of the proxy model, use the
            // getHttpApiV2ProxyHandler
            // method: handler =
            // SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getHttpApiV2ProxyHandler(Application.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.info(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
        handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
    }
}

